# How can I fix this count report, FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to create an sql statement

```
 SELECT   ACTIVITY_ID, ACTIVITY_DESCRIPTION,
```

I've selected task activity because it joins the 4 tables together

```
 COUNT(*) NAME AS NAMECount
```

I use the above count statement to count the number of volunteers

```
 DESCRIPTION AS TASK
 FROM
```

here's the inner join

```
 TASK_ACTIVITY
 INNER JOIN
 VOLUNTEER ON VOLUNTEER.VOLUNTEER_ID = TASK_ACTIVITY.VOLUNTEER_ID
 INNER JOIN
 TASK ON TASK.TASK_ID = TASK_ACTIVITY.TASK_ID
 GROUP BY VOLUNTEER.NAME;
```

and I get this error

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: update you question and add  the exact query code  please

Comment: First you are missing `,` after `NAMECount` column

Comment: What is `count(*) NAME as NAMEcount` supposed to do? Did you mean `count(NAME) as NAMEcount`? As written, you have `count(*)`, `NAME` is seen as an alias for this value, and `as NAMEcount` is out of place and causes the error you saw. Now, after you fix this you will get other errors. If you want a `count(...)` in a query that returns all rows from the join, not just a summary such as `count(...)`, then you will need to use the *analytic* version of `count()`. You will do **much** better if you explain the requirement, instead of just showing broken code.

Comment: the requirement is volunteer database with volunteer table task table task activity table and project table task activity linked to volunteer task activity is linked to task and task is linked to project all i want to do is make an SQL statement that reads the amount of students on certain tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below query. Provide the alias in the column names and group by columns to make it work as you did not mention what column belongs to what table

```
SELECT   ACTIVITY_ID,
 ACTIVITY_DESCRIPTION,
COUNT(*), NAME AS NAMECount,
 DESCRIPTION AS TASK
 FROM TASK_ACTIVITY TASK_ACTIVITY
 INNER JOIN
 VOLUNTEER VOLUNTEER 
ON VOLUNTEER.VOLUNTEER_ID = TASK_ACTIVITY.VOLUNTEER_ID
 INNER JOIN
 TASK ON TASK.TASK_ID = TASK_ACTIVITY.TASK_ID
 GROUP BY ACTIVITY_ID, ACTIVITY_DESCRIPTION, TASK, VOLUNTEER.NAME;
```

Comment: THANKYOU VERY MUCH

Comment: yes i did work could you help me ive got another one that i need to count the amout people in a certain place

Comment: SELECT 
ACTIVITY_ID,ACTIVITY_DESCRIPTION,
         Name,
         DESCRIPTION,
         PROJECT_NAME AS PROJECT
         FROM
         TASK_ACTIVITY
         INNER JOIN
         VOLUNTEER ON VOLUNTEER.VOLUNTEER_ID = TASK_ACTIVITY.VOLUNTEER_ID
         INNER JOIN
         TASK ON TASK.TASK_ID = TASK_ACTIVITY.TASK_ID
         INNER JOIN
         PROJECT ON PROJECT.PROJECT_ID = TASK.PROJECT_ID;

Comment: answer the question how many students went india on my tables

Comment: is there any column describing country name?

Comment: yes have you got an email i could send you the tables and the column names ?

Comment: Ya. jimmacaulay3318@gmail.com. Let me know once you mailed

Comment: yeah ive sent it over